# 15 wall mount monitors displaying the same video through LAN?

Tags: display, lan, external-display, video-streaming

We want to have announcement/info monitors around our office and we want to stream it all from the same PC. Is it possible to do this via LAN or what's the best cost effective solution to achieve this?

Comment: @alecxs I don't know if there are monitors with ethernet port. I am asking if there are available LAN to HDMI switches and stuff. Very new to this.

Comment: some advertisement (i am not affiliated) https://monitorsanywhere.com/hdmi-over-lan-explained

Comment: I had seen that earlier but it's just a software isn't it? How do you physically make the connection between one server PC and multiple monitors to use that software?

Comment: probably something like this https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08DCTGN8J